# Hibernate Test - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got this error.. Could someone help me ?

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   cidade.CidadeJpaController.getEntityManager(CidadeJpaController.java:24)
>     at cidade.CidadeJpaController.create(CidadeJpaController.java:30)   at
>   Main.Main.main(Main.java:10) Java Result: 1

Cidade

```
package cidade;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Cidade implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String nome;
    private String uf;

    public Cidade() {
    }

    public Cidade(String n, String u){
        this.nome = n;
        this.uf = u;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="easyjavajpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>cidade.Cidade</class>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/thibernate"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

CidadeJpaController

```
package cidade;

import cidade.exceptions.NonexistentEntityException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public class CidadeJpaController implements Serializable {

    public CidadeJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public CidadeJpaController() {
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(Cidade cidade) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(cidade);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void edit(Cidade cidade) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            cidade = em.merge(cidade);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
                long id = cidade.getId();
                if (findCidade(id) == null) {
                    throw new NonexistentEntityException("The cidade with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy(long id) throws NonexistentEntityException {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Cidade cidade;
            try {
                cidade = em.getReference(Cidade.class, id);
                cidade.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The cidade with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
            }
            em.remove(cidade);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Cidade> findCidadeEntities() {
        return findCidadeEntities(true, -1, -1);
    }

    public List<Cidade> findCidadeEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        return findCidadeEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
    }

    private List<Cidade> findCidadeEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(Cidade.class));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all) {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public Cidade findCidade(long id) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            return em.find(Cidade.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public int getCidadeCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            Root<Cidade> rt = cq.from(Cidade.class);
            cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Main

```
    package Main;

    import java.util.*; 
    import cidade.*; 

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
            CidadeJpaController em = new CidadeJpaController();
            Cidade cidade = new Cidade("Santarém", "PA"); 
            em.create(cidade); 
            List cidades = em.findCidadeEntities(); 
            System.out.println( cidades.size() + " cidade(s) encontradas" ); 
            for (Object c : cidades) { 
            Cidade cid = (Cidade) c;
            System.out.println(cid.getNome()); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not setting the entityManagerFactory while instantiating your controller. Hence it is throwing a null pointer exception. As per your code

```
 em = getEntityManager();
```

the getEntityManagerMethod():

```
 public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

Here emf is already null. As you used default constructor to initialize your code and I do not see any injection what so ever.

Regards
Himanshu

Comment: Then using the constructor , as I would in main?

public CidadeJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

Comment: Please refer some guide like getting started guide on hibernate. There they explain how to declare and inject your EntityManagerFactory. This is the very begining of hibernate. One of the good reads you can find [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#d0e996)

Comment: I put...public CidadeJpaController() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("easyjavajpa");
    }

Comment: Did it worked? If yes then please close the question or let us know the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have this constructor in CidadeJpaController which takes EntityManagerFactory object.

```
 public CidadeJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
```

While instantiating you're not providing EntityManagerFactory object resulting in null pointer error when trying to access. SO create an EntityManagerFactory object ans send it CidadeJpaController.Below is a sample solution change it in your Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("easyjavajpa");
            CidadeJpaController em = new CidadeJpaController(entityManagerFactory);
            Cidade cidade = new Cidade("Santarém", "PA"); 
            em.create(cidade); 
        List cidades = em.findCidadeEntities();
```